# AWS API gateway throwing CORS errors

Tags: aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudfront

I have a, api stack behind API Gateway. I use connexion and I have a code where it adds CORS related response.

```
app = connexion.FlaskApp(__name__, specification_dir='swagger/')
app.add_api('swagger.yaml', arguments={'title': 'MyApp Server'})
app.app.json_encoder = JSONEncoder
CORS(app.app)
app.run()
```

I have made sure that cors is enabled on teh api gateway side.
I can run all the api endpoints using curl.
my request headers via curl (I have added -H 'ORIGIN:http://localhost:8080' to simulate a browser behavior).

```
> POST /dev/current/login HTTP/2
> Host: <host>.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
> Origin: http://localhost:8080
```

The response I get

```
< HTTP/2 200 
< content-type: application/json
< content-length: 560
< date: Fri, 17 Jan 2020 21:08:20 GMT
< x-amzn-requestid: <>
< access-control-allow-origin: http://localhost:8080
< x-amzn-remapped-content-length: 560
< x-amz-apigw-id: <>
< vary: Origin
...
```

I am trying to build a web application. When I simulate a similar behavior, I get CORS error.

```
:path: /dev/current/login
:scheme: https
accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9
content-length: 342
content-type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
origin: http://localhost:8080
referer: http://localhost:8080/
sec-fetch-mode: cors
```

response

```
content-encoding: gzip
content-length: 43
content-type: application/json
date: Fri, 17 Jan 2020 20:31:02 GMT
status: 403
via: 1.1 <CF Host>.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)

x-amzn-errortype: ForbiddenException
x-cache: Error from cloudfront
```

What am I doing wrong.

My client is written in react.

```
Axios.post('https://<host>.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/current/login', {
        headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
            'X-Api-Key': 'API key',
            'ORIGIN': 'http://localhost:443',

        }
    }).then(v => console.log(v)).catch(c => console.log(c));
```

Comment: no custom domain for API gateway?

Comment: None as of now.

Comment: I can understand that you have an API and its working fine when you test it. But I don't follow from the line it says "I am trying to build a web application."

Comment: It looks like you are running the website code in your local machine, i dont follow how the cloudfront is involved in the error message.

Comment: Yes. I am testing the client code on my local machine. Just a simple html code. If I run the server on my local machine, I dont get this error.
I am not quite sure how cloudfront is coming into picture either. 
My observation so far is that the preflight request and response is good (200 response with the right headers in the response) but the subsequent post call results in a 403 (cors error)

Comment: something on this lines https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/enhanced-cloudfront-customization/

Comment: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=647833 - API Gateway integrates with CloudFront behind the scenes. We automatically create a global CloudFront distribution for your APIs in order to reduce the latency perceived by end users. However, the API Gateway cache is handled in the region where API Gateway runs and your API is deployed. Requests are accepted by the CloudFront PoP and then sent to the API Gateway in its origin region, that's where API Gateway will check against its cache and return a cached response if possible.

Comment: so are you saying its working through curl but not through react, can you post your full curl command

Comment: ```curl -I -X POST  -H 'x-api-key: <API KEY>' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' https://server.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/devcurrent/login``` works

Comment: this was long time ago. but have you solved it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your the API is expecting the origin to be `http://localhost:8080`.

It doesn't look like that you are sending the request from the host `http://localhost:8080` since I see that your react code is setting the origin to `'ORIGIN': 'http://localhost:443'`

I suggest you set the API cors to allow requests from `*` to see if the error you are getting is related to cors( i am pretty sure it is). Once you get it working, then you can set it to the specific domain.

Hope this helps.